# Provided Js lib A exists but not as npm consumables, What are the ways to make it work with npm based angularjs app with typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

We are trying to create a reusable components which will be published to internal repo. This is an angularjs 1.5+ project with typescript. The project is configured to use webpack. Now this module needs a JavaScript library so I was wondering what are the ways to do it? Also any recommendations for best practices would be nice.

Comment: If you want to publish something and got dependency on something that is not published - just add it as usual file to your app.

Comment: Agreed but if we do so how does webpack plays with that ? Would that be a victim of treeshaking ?